# VBA stops running after filtering data, but with no error message

Tags: vba, excel, advanced-filter

I am trying to filter data using the advanced filter, and then copy the visible cells to a separate sheet in the workbook:

```
Dim S_ALR, OUTPUTS, INPUTS As Worksheet
Set S_ALR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S_ALR_87012357")
Set OUTPUTS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTPUTS")

'clear data
Worksheets("OUTPUTS").Range("A:AK").ClearContents

'copy Outputs from S_ALR_87012357 to OUTPUTS tab

S_ALR.Range("A:AK").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets("FILTERS").Range("A3:B9"), Unique:=False
S_ALR.Range("A:AK").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
OUTPUTS.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

However, after the data is filtered the macro stops with no error message.

I have commented out the filter and ran the macro & the rest of the code works properly. I have also tried incorporating the copy/past into the filter itself by putting CopyToRange in the filter, but that also hasn't worked.

I'm quite new to this, so it may be something simple that I am missing, but I'm absolutely stumped!
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "stops"?  Is it simply *finished*? You can find out by stepping through the code with F8 and checking relevant vaiable values along the way.  More Info: [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) from Chip Pearson.

Comment: Does the macro really stops execution or does it fail to do the copy/paste thing? Debug your code or put a `Debug.print "I am alive"` statement after the Filter and check the output in the *Immediate window*

Comment: Is there any other event code in the workbook (such as a `Worksheet_Calculate` event) or any UDFs being used in conditional formatting?

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` statement anywhere in that sub/function?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but thought I'd add an answer as I've just had the same issue and spent an hour looking into it. Turns out the fix seems to just be restarting Excel (closing down all Excel windows and reopening), and the AdvancedFilter line executed without issue for me after that.

For reference my line of code that exhibited the same behaviour was:

`Range("B1:B1808").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True`

In response to the original question's comments:

- Yes the code just stops, I stepped through my code, got to the Advanced Filter line, the AdvancedFilter line is then executed but the next line doesn't get stepped into, it's as if the AdvancedFilter line acted like an 'End' command
- The AdvancedFilter line's execution succeeded, VBA just didn't continue onto the next line for some reason. I put a debug.print line after and it was never exectuted.
- No Worksheet_Calculate event was being triggered, the workbook I was doing my testing in only had that single AdvancedFilter line of code (within a 'sub test' - 'end sub' of course)
- While testing I explicitly added an 'On Error GoTo 0' before the AdvancedFilter line and this had no effect